# How to use IHttpClientFactory in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, mef, httpclientfactory

I am trying to convert some code from net core api to class library.

I am stuck how to use HttpClientfactory.
Normally the httpclientfactory can be configured in program.cs or Startup like

```
services.AddHttpClient("abc", xxx config).
```

How to do configurations in class library for Httpclientfactory.

Comment: you do not as class library will be used in a project where you'll add HttpClientFactory, or you can add your own ServiceCollection extension which will add HttpClientFactory

Comment: We are using MEF. where we will just load the dlls. can you give an example on ServiceCollection extensions

Answer (score 1):

You could try as below:

```
public class HttpClientUtil
    {
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; } 

        public static void Initial(IServiceProvider Provider)
        {
            if (Provider == null)
            {
                IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
                builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHttpClient("client_1", config =>
                    {
                        config.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://client_1.com");
                        config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("header_1", "header_1");
                    });
                    services.AddHttpClient("client_2", config =>
                    {
                        config.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://client_2.com");
                        config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("header_2", "header_2");
                    });
                });
                serviceProvider = builder.Build().Services;
            }
            else
            {
                serviceProvider = Provider;
            } 
        }

        public static IHttpClientFactory GetHttpClientFactory()
        {
            if(serviceProvider==null)
            {
                Initial(serviceProvider);
            }
            return (IHttpClientFactory)serviceProvider.GetServices<IHttpClientFactory>();
        }

    }
```

you could get the instance of httpclinetfactory through the interface

Comment: for replacing `return (IHttpClientFactory)serviceProvider.GetServices<IHttpClientFactory>();` with `return (IHttpClientFactory)serviceProvider.GetServices<IHttpClientFactory>().First();` worked

Answer (score 1):

In your library add an extension method for `IServiceCollection` to "enable" it in the main project.

In the library:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExt
{
    public static void AddYourStaff(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient("xxx", client =>
        {
            //your staff here
        });
        services.AddSingleton<ISomethingElse, SomethingElse>();
    }
}
```

Then in your `Startup` just call it:

```
services.AddYourStaff();
```

**UPDATE:** As the author described, he's working on the plugin based application. In that case you need some kind of convention, for instance:

1. each plugin library must have a public static class called `Registration` with public static method `Invoke(IServiceCollection sc, IConfiguration config)`
2. Then in your `Startup` you can iterate through all plugin libraries and call their `Registration.Invoke(sc, config)` using reflection:

```
foreach(var pluginAssembly in plugins)
{
    pluginAssembly
        .GetType("Registration")
        .GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] {services, Configuration});
}
```

Comment: i don't have a startup.. i will send call to class library and that will manage. Actually i am building plugin based architecture where different plugin will manage its own httpclients.

Comment: @Bezhas Then you should show more code than you have. Anyway, on your plugin you ought to add something that you can pass the `iServiceCollection` to. If your library requires dependency injection, how are you currently using it without having access to the service collection?

Comment: @Bezhas updated the answer for your particular case.

Comment: @Bezhas added a code sample how to call plugins' registrations.

Comment: @mtkachenko   var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    var catThisAssembly = new AssemblyCatalog(assem);

                    var catAgg = new AggregateCatalog(lstPluginsDirCatalogs);
                    catAgg.Catalogs.Add(catThisAssembly);
                    var compose = new CompositionContainer(catAgg);
                    this.BalanceParent = this;
                    compose.ComposeParts(this)

Comment: @Bezhas I have no Idea how your implementation of plugins works internally. And this code snippet doesn't help. I suppose each plugin is located in a separate assembly, just try to extend your implementation with what I wrote.